# gulp-eslint fails to parse optional chaining syntax

Tags: javascript, gulp, eslint, gulp-eslint

I'm trying to lint JavaScript code with optional chaining syntax like:

`let foo = bar?.property;`

When parsing my JS files with `eslint` explicitly, it passes.

When parsing with `gulp-eslint` using the same configuration, linting fails with:

> Parsing error: Unexpected token .

My `.eslintrc.json` file contains:

```
{
    "parserOptions": {
      "ecmaVersion": 2020
    }
}
```

My Gulp task looks like:

```
const eslint = require('gulp-eslint');

return gulp.src(['src/**/*.js'])
    .pipe(eslint({ configFile: '.eslintrc.json' }))
    .pipe(eslint.formatEach('compact', process.stderr))
    .pipe(eslint.failAfterError());
```

I'm using the following packages:

```
"devDependencies": {
    "eslint": "^8.2.0",
    "gulp": "4.0.2",
    "gulp-eslint": "^6.0.0",
  }
```

Am I missing something, or is there a viable workaround?

Comment: gulp-eslint uses ESLint 6. I guess the standalone ESLint you are running must be the newer 8.2 version.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm having the same problem.

Comment: @dshapiro We have moved away from `gulp` completely since then, but since `gulp-eslint` is 3 years old I'm guessing it's abandoned and was using an older `eslint` version.

Answer (score 0):

The ecmaVersion parser option can't be used like that, see https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring/language-options#specifying-environments.
Changing it from 2020 to 11 or 12 or "latest" should work.

Comment: Thanks, but setting to `2020` is valid according to the docs. If you look under https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring/language-options#specifying-parser-options it says: "2020 (same as 11)"